# Artificial dataset generator for classification data

Tags: r, distributions, machine-learning, classification

I would like to generate some artificial data to evaluate an algorithm for classification (the algorithm induces a model that predicts posterior probabilities).

These are some basic properties of the dataset:

- Features have to be continuous
- Response variable is dichotomous (either 0 or 1)

I would like to test whether the algorithm can cope with:

- Many feature / high dimensional problems
- noise (it can drop features)
- Multi-modality
- ??? (how do I simulate correlation etc.)

I intend to implement the algorithm in R or Matlab. I can sample from multivariate normal distributions and specify  a covariance matrix.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Have you looked into using a real-world pre-existing dataset? There are many advantages to using real-world data instead of synthetic data. I can immediately think of at least one type of problem that follows your criteria: vision classification. For example, in the MNIST dataset the features are pixel values and the response variable is a handwritten digit ('0'-'9'). edit: Just saw that you want binary classification, in the case of MNIST you could subset the data, for example try to classify zeros vs non-zeros.

Comment: Sorry I disaggree. As I produce probabilities an artifical generator would also allow me to test the calibration. This would (IMHO) be impossible using real-world datasets. It would also be hard to see under which conditions (e.g. above 10 higly correlated features) the algorithm starts to fail ... etc.

Comment: Please, keep us informed on your progress with your related question on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8972244/420055.

Comment: I will have a look at the R mlbench package today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some idea might be to generate something like the [Madelon set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Madelon) from NIPS 2003 challenge; it fits your requirements pretty well.

You can generate a set like this starting with `mlbench.xor` (or `mlbench.hypercube`, might be easier) form mlbench package, then you combine classes it generated into two groups to make the dichotomous response and add new attributes to increase dimensionality -- some being random linear combinations of the original ones, some being just random noise.

Comment: MADELON has train.labels only, no test.labels not valid.labels. (In fact all the NIPS 2003 datasets on uciml, arcene dexter dorothea gisette, have only train.labels. Can anyone find the test.labels ?)